# Delete words beginning with pattern in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I try to delete all words, starting with -L from string. Example:

Input:

```
-L/home/a -la -L/home/b -lb
```

Output:

```
-la -lb
```

Do you know nice and short solution for it. My idea doesnt work:

```
echo $(sed 's/-L\w//g' <<< "-L/home/a -la -L/home/b -lb")
```

Comment: what does `<<<` mean i never seen it

Comment: @DevZer0 It's called a "here string", described in `man bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close:

```
$ echo '-L/home/a -la -L/home/b -lb' | sed 's/-L[^[:space:]]*//g'
 -la  -lb
```

Or if you don't have other whitespace than spaces, just

```
$ echo '-L/home/a -la -L/home/b -lb' | sed 's/-L[^ ]*//g'
 -la  -lb
```

You might still need to strip excessive spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You've been almost there: slashes are non-word-characters and you need to match multiple charcters, so try:

```
echo $(sed 's/-L\S*//g' <<< "-L/home/a -la -L/home/b -lb")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sed

```
echo "-L/home/a -la -L/home/b -lb" | sed 's/-L[^ ]*//g'
```

If you don't want to have more spaces and space on the first line

```
sed 's/-L[^ ]*//g;s/^ //' file.txt | tr -s " "
```